# ¿Por qué en Chrome no puedo ver los cambios que hago en mi página web?

Tags: html5, css3, google-chrome

Estoy haciendo una página web con HTML, CSS y JS, pero el problema es que cuando actualizo en Chrome después de cada cambio en mi codigo, no se actualiza la página, y el código sigue siendo el mismo que antes. Al contrario que cuando hago lo mismo en Internet Explorer, ahí sí se actualizan los cambios y el código. ¿Alguien sabe cual es la razón?

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ASPATPERU-SISBIO</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat''>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/inicio.css">


</head>

<body>
 <div id=bannerimagen>
  <img id="banner" src="img/portadainicio.jpg"/>
 </div>

  <div class="contenedor-menu">
<ul class="accordion-menu">
  <li>
    <div class="dropdownlink"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> PACIENTES
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="submenuItems">
      <li><a href="#">History book 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">History book 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">History book 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdownlink"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fiction
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="submenuItems">
      <li><a href="#">Fiction book 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fiction book 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fiction book 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/inicio.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Código CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion-menu {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 60px auto 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.contenedor-menu{
  position:absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 16px;

}

.accordion-menu li.open .dropdownlink {
  color: #CDDC39;
}
.accordion-menu li.open .dropdownlink .fa-chevron-down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion-menu li:last-child .dropdownlink {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.dropdownlink {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #212121;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.dropdownlink i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 16px;
}
.dropdownlink .fa-chevron-down {
  right: -15px;
  left: auto;
}

.submenuItems {
  display: none;
  background: #C8E6C9;
}
.submenuItems li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B6B6B6;
}

.submenuItems a {
  display: block;
  color: #727272;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 45px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.submenuItems a:hover {
  background-color: #CDDC39;
  color: #fff;
}


#banner{
   position: absolute;
  top:  0px; 
  left: 20%;
  right: 10%
  width :300px;
}
```

Vista en Chrome:

[image: VISTA DE CHROME]

Vista en Internet Explorer

[image: VISTA EN INTERNET EXPLORER]

Comment: Con solo pulsar [F5] la pagina es cargada del cache del explorador, debes pulsar [CTRL] + [F5] para cargar la pagina del sitio WEB y actualizar el cache.

Answer (score 4):

Desactiva el cache en la pestaña Network o Red del panel de Herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien puede agregar versionamiento a tus archivos y subirlo mientras haces actualizaciones:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/inicio.css?v=0.0.1">`

Answer (score 1):

También puedes presionar `Ctrl-Shift-N`, lo cual abre una ventana de incógnito. Ésta es la forma más simple y rápida de tener una instancia nueva, sin que caché o cookies interfieran. Yo siempre hago eso cuando un cambio no se refleja y quiero asegurarme que no sea problema de caché del navegador.

Por cierto, en Opera y Vivaldi la combinación de teclas es la misma. Para Internet Explorer y Firefox, es `Ctrl-Shift-P`.

Otra opción más es agregar un parámetro en la url, como por ejemplo `/tupagina?v=89234982734`. De hecho esto es lo que hace jQuery de forma automática cuando le indicas que no cachee el request GET.